# Failed to find database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So it seems that when I run the file register.php (which contains some basic html forms to send to a database) it cannot find the specific database that it is looking for. All files are with in the same folder, and the spelling is correct.

So I will paste the php code that is above all the html/css code in my register.php

```
    <?php
$link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  $database='salesinformation';              
  if (!$link)
  die('Failed to connect to Server'.mysql_error());
  $db=mysql_select_db($database, $link);
  session_start();
  if(!$db)
  die('Failed to select Data Base '.mysql_error());

  if(isset($_GET['process']))
   {
    $query = "Insert INTO `sales` (Username, Email, Price, Condition, RegisterDate) values('$_POST[Username]', '$_POST[Email]','$_POST[Price]','$_POST[Condition]','$_POST[RegisteredDate]')";
    //echo $query; exit;
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if(!$result){
        $msg = "not Inserted";
    }
    else
    {
     $msg = "Inserted";
     header("location:ClientList.php?m=".$msg);
    }
   }
?>
```

And I have the database file salesinformation.sql in the same folder which contains this code..

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales` (
  `Username` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Price` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Condition` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `RegisterDate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Username`)
);
```

*So this happens when I run xampp "`http://localhost/register.php`"
Failed to select Data Base Unknown database 'salesinformation'*

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: when I run xampp "http://localhost/register.php" Failed to select Data Base Unknown database 'salesinformation'

Comment: Check the spelling of the actual database name.

Comment: Side note. Use the `mysqli` function instead of the mysql.

Answer (score 1):

> And I have the database file salesinformation.sql in the same folder which contains this code..

That does not mean you have a MySQL database.

1) Create a MySQL database named `salesinformation`.

2) Import your SQL file into that database.

3) Now you have one. Now run your code.

> Could you write what to type in the terminal (Since I cant find any GUI of the xampp while running it in ubuntu)? How do I create the "MySQL" database? and how to I import a SQL file into it?

1. Using terminal, type `CREATE DATABASE salesinformation;`
2. Using shell `cd` go to the directory where your `salesinformation.sql` file resides.
3. Issue this command `mysql -u root -p password salesinformation < salesinformation.sql`.

Note: Since I noticed from your code your root password is blank, you can remove the `password` term from the above command. If you do have a password type it there then

Comment: Could you write what to type in the terminal (Since I cant find any GUI of the xampp while running it in ubuntu)? 
How do I create the "MySQL" database? and how to I import a SQL file into it?

Comment: Thanks, I understand. The problem right now is I dont know how to start the MySQL shell. When I did this in Windows I just clicked a mySql file and a prompt started etc...

But I have no idea how to start the sql prompt in the terminal so I can write the "CREATE DATABASE ..." etc

xampp seems to be working:
`"Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.1...
XAMPP: XAMPP-Apache is already running.
XAMPP: XAMPP-MySQL is already running.
XAMPP: XAMPP-ProFTPD is already running.
XAMPP for Linux started.`

But how to start the sql prompt?

Comment: Found it. It was just 
`/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root`

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: Username in /opt/lampp/htdocs/studenthoj/register.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: Email in /opt/lampp/htdocs/studenthoj/register.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: Price in /opt/lampp/htdocs/studenthoj/register.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: Condition in /opt/lampp/htdocs/studenthoj/register.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: RegisteredDate in /opt/lampp/htdocs/studenthoj/register.php on line 15
You have an error in your SQL syntax; blabla.. to use near 'Condition, RegisterDate) values('', '','','','')' at line 1`

Some real errors now..

Comment: Now those errors are related to your PHP code and that's another question